# Leaflet features work on some browsers, but not all

Tags: leaflet, easybutton-plugin

So I'm having a strange issue with Leaflet plug-ins, certain features will fail on certain browsers. The site is is at-
https://samdotson1992.github.io/KY_beer/

It seems to work on:

- IE11
- Edge

But does not work on-

- Chrome
- Firefox

Note the basemap will map will appear regardless, but the points won't load from the CSV and my other features fail too. Everything is on GitHub at https://github.com/samdotson1992/KY_beer.

Any suggestions? Ideas?

Comment: There are some Mixed Content warnings: ´Mixed Content: The page at 'https://samdotson1992.github.io/KY_beer/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.domoritz.de/leaflet-locatecontrol/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.´

Answer (score 2):

Loading the map in Chrome gives the following error (Press F12 to see the errors in your local browser):

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://samdotson1992.github.io/KY_beer/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.domoritz.de/leaflet-locatecontrol/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Despite using a https link for including the locatecontrol plugin, it obviously redirects to a non-https site of the developer shown in the error message. While Chrome is more strict about not loading the content, e.g. Edge just shows a warning message in the developer console but still loads the files.

As a result the functions from this plugin are not available in Chrome, which results in a broken map.

You can fix that by including the plugin via e.g. the JsDelivr CDN (which actually is the preferred way mentioned on the [github page](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol#add-the-javascript-and-css-files) of the plugin). You need to adapt just the lines 22 and 24 in your index.html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.locatecontrol@0.62.0/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet.locatecontrol@0.62.0/src/L.Control.Locate.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```